# Replacing a square with a star in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

In the code below I would like to replace the box by a star. How do I do this?

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{center} \begin{tikzpicture}   \draw (0,1.5) node[fill,inner sep=2pt] (D1) {}; \end{tikzpicture} \end{center}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `shapes.geometric` library (see section "71.3 Geometric Shapes" of the user manual) provides a `star` shape:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{center} 
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\draw (0,1.5) node[fill,inner sep=20pt,star] (D1) {}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Might be an idea to refer to the manual, as `shapes.geometric` is not always easy to find.

Comment: @daleif Added the section to search for

Comment: Thanks for that. Now I realise I should have asked for an asterisk, not a star.

Comment: @ZoltanFleishman `\draw (0,1.5) node[scale=3] (D1) {*}; ` and scale as needed